# Unexpected behavior for TSLint in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

I am using Angular to build a project and recently switched from VS Code to WebStorm and am having trouble making sense of this. Below are some tests I ran just to make sure everything was in order.

I am defining the return type of the `test()` function as a `string` but returning a `boolean` and it is not throwing an error. However when I randomly write in an undeclared variable it throws the wrong error, it says expected assignment when it should be undeclared variable. Below it I just call the test function like so `test()` just to see if it throws the correct error when the function is called; no dice.

Here is the code:

```
function test(): string {
  return true;
}

bob;
bob = 1;
test();
```

[image: wrong errors]

Here is my TS.CONFIG:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Here is TS.LINT:

```
{
  "extends": "tslint:recommended",
  "rules": {
    "array-type": false,
    "arrow-parens": false,
    "deprecation": {
      "severity": "warning"
    },
    "component-class-suffix": true,
    "contextual-lifecycle": true,
    "directive-class-suffix": true,
    "directive-selector": [
      true,
      "attribute",
      "app",
      "camelCase"
    ],
    "component-selector": [
      true,
      "element",
      "app",
      "kebab-case"
    ],
    "import-blacklist": [
      true,
      "rxjs/Rx"
    ],
    "interface-name": false,
    "max-classes-per-file": false,
    "max-line-length": [
      true,
      140
    ],
    "member-access": false,
    "member-ordering": [
      true,
      {
        "order": [
          "static-field",
          "instance-field",
          "static-method",
          "instance-method"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "no-consecutive-blank-lines": false,
    "no-console": [
      true,
      "debug",
      "info",
      "time",
      "timeEnd",
      "trace"
    ],
    "no-empty": false,
    "no-inferrable-types": [
      true,
      "ignore-params"
    ],
    "no-non-null-assertion": true,
    "no-redundant-jsdoc": true,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-var-requires": false,
    "object-literal-key-quotes": [
      true,
      "as-needed"
    ],
    "no-bitwise": false,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "ordered-imports": false,
    "quotemark": [
      true,
      "single"
    ],
    "trailing-comma": false,
    "no-conflicting-lifecycle": true,
    "no-host-metadata-property": true,
    "no-input-rename": true,
    "no-inputs-metadata-property": true,
    "no-output-native": true,
    "no-output-on-prefix": true,
    "no-output-rename": false,
    "no-outputs-metadata-property": true,
    "template-banana-in-box": true,
    "template-no-negated-async": true,
    "use-lifecycle-interface": true,
    "use-pipe-transform-interface": true
  },
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "codelyzer"
  ]
}
```

**Edit:**
TypeScript isn't working at all here. I defined a parameter and set the parameter type to string then passed it an integer and got no error:

[image: wrong error 2]

Comment: From what i'm guessing, you are initializing an empty variable ? But you don't have any `var` or `let`. Maybe try adding that ?

Comment: I wrote it wrong on purpose to make sure ts lint is working; the question is in regards as to why ts lint isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you need to save the file so that it recompiles and throws the correct errors

[image: fixed]